# VBA web scraping contents without class name or ID

Tags: vba, web-scraping, getelementsbyclassname

I would like to scrape Dividend Future Prices from HKEX.

Here's the URL of this site : 
http://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Futures-and-Options-Prices/Equity-Index/HSCEI-Dividend-Futures?sc_lang=en#&product=DHH

I wanted to scrape Prev.Day settlement price of the "Dec-19 Contract" via VBA.
However, it doesn't have any class name or id, so I have no idea how to access the information.

```
<tr>
  <td>Dec-19</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>413.78</td>
  <td>
    -
    <br>
    -
  </td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>
    -
    <br>
    -
  </td>
    <td>-<td>
    <td>17,330</td>
  </tr>
```

How can I scrape this via VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really the hell of an automation to find specific item with no remarkable flag attached to it. However, I've written this script without hardcoding index to the elements. Give this a shot and get your desired values:

```
Sub Hkex_Data()

    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim posts As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .navigate "http://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Futures-and-Options-Prices/Equity-Index/HSCEI-Dividend-Futures?sc_lang=en#&product=DHH"
        Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Set html = .document
    End With
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

    For Each posts In html.getElementsByClassName("hsirowcon")
        Row = Row + 1: Cells(Row, 1) = posts.NextSibling.NextSibling.FirstChild.innerText
        Cells(Row, 2) = posts.NextSibling.NextSibling.LastChild.innerText
    Next posts

    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Result:

```
19-Dec  17,330
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
Microsoft internet controls
Microsoft Html Object Library
```

Comment: I scraped higher class and find all the items inside it. But your code looks much better, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use getElementsByTagName. Identify your  and then go through each row and each td in rows. Something like that.

```
Dim objTR As IHTMLElement
Dim objTD As IHTMLElement
Dim objTable As IHTMLElement

For Each objTR In objTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    For Each objTD In objTR
        'do something with objtd.innerText
    Next objTD
Next objTR
```

or you can declare your variables as Object if you prefer late binding.

Answer (score 1):

You could also simply use a CSS selector and no loop:

```
html.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(4)")(1).innerText
```

This method is fragile. If the style on the page changes this may break.

---

**CSS selector:**

If you observe the relevant part of the page (showing first contract year with headers for context and with chart between contract years removed):

[image: Contract info]

The associated HTML for contract year 2019 is:

[image: HTML]

`Prev.Day Settlement Price` is the 4th `td` within this i.e. CSS selector `td:nth-child(4)`.

This pattern is repeated for all contract years so you can return a nodeList of all matches to this (i.e. every `td:nth-child(4)` with the `.querySelectorAll` method).

Year 2019 is at index position 1; this is the second element in a 0 based indexed nodeList, so you access with  `.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(4)")(1)`.

---

**CSS query result - first few results:**

[image: CSS query]